# How to fix simple quotation error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on simple code to print variables from a for loop and I am stuck on the 4th line of the code. I get an `invalid syntax error`. Any help would be appreciated. My desired output is

```
print('-----------------------------------------')
print(output1)
print('-----------------------------------------')
print(output4)
print('-----------------------------------------')
print(output2)
print('-----------------------------------------')
print(output3)
print('-----------------------------------------')
print(output5)
print('-----------------------------------------')
```

-code below

```
printt=[1,4,2,3,5]
for numm in printt:
    print('-----------------------------------------')
    print(output'%d',%(numm))
```

Comment: What is `output'%d'` supposed to do exactly? format the output or append two strings?

Comment: your `output` is not defined, is it a variable or is it just some string you want to print. if it is string then it should be inside quotation marks.

Comment: output is a variable. i would like to join the output variable with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: @mikerosd So you're trying to access variables `output1`, `output2`, etc?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, YES exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code has output1, output2, output3, output4 and output5 as variables.
It would be better if you use a list.
like:

```
_output_list = [output1, output4, output2, output3, output5]
for _out in _output_list:
    print('-----------------------------------------')
    print(_out)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think, the below would be helpful.

```
>>> printt=[1,4,2,3,5]
>>> for numm in printt:
...     print('-----------------------------------------')
...     print('output%d' % (numm))
...
-----------------------------------------
output1
-----------------------------------------
output4
-----------------------------------------
output2
-----------------------------------------
output3
-----------------------------------------
output5
>>>
```

Comment: I believe that this person has assigned values to `output1 = ...` et. al., and is attempting to output those values dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The output variable is not defined in this case. You should change it output to 'output'.

```
print('output%d' % (numm))
```

or

```
print('output%d'.format(numm))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line instead:

```
 print('output{}').format(numm)
```